# One to One relationship with both tables having multiple entries (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, one-to-one

I'm having trouble trying to implement this database; I have three tables Courses, Schedules, and Students.

Students have 
studentID, name, GPA, etc.

Schedules have 
ID, course1, course2, course3

Courses have 
courseID, courseName, courseAbbv, courseCredits, courseDepartment

Students.studentID and Schedules.ID have a one to one relationship 
and 
Courses.courseID has a one to many relationship with Schedules.course1,course2,course3

I want to make a query where I can display a students schedule so:

studentName, course1, course2, course3
where course1, course2, course3= courseAbbv

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the tables to have the following relationships.

**Student**

•   Student_Id (PK)

**Schedule**

•   Schedule_Id (PK)

•   Course_Id (FK)

•   Student_Id (FK)

**Course**

•   Course_Id (PK)

Your schedule table shouldn't contain columns per course, but rather a reference to the course table.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add some of the foreign keys. The course1, course2, and course3 in my Schedules table are foreign keys referencing the Courses table. However I can't seem to display the course name whenever I create a query with the relationship

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: SELECT studentName, course1, course2, course3
FROM Students, Schedules, Courses
WHERE Students.studentID = Schedules.studentID AND Schedules.course1 = Courses.ID AND
Schedules.course2 = Courses.ID AND Schedules.course3 = Courses.ID;

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this site, tried formatting it but couldn't get it to work

Comment: You wont get any data back from the following query because Course 1, Course 2 and Course 3 are all going to be different, your query assumes they're the same.

If you want to do it using a product join, you would need to provide aliases for the course table names

Comment: SELECT  studentName ,
        Course1.CourseName ,
        course2.CourseName  ,
        course3.CourseName 
FROM    Students ,
        Schedules ,
        Courses Course1,
  Courses Course2,
  Courses Cource3
WHERE   Students.studentID = Schedules.studentID
        AND Schedules.course1 = Course1.ID
        AND Schedules.course2 = Course2.ID
        AND Schedules.course3 = Course3.ID

Comment: This is how the table structure should look like, except: **get rid of `Student.Schedule_Id`**. The junction table `Schedule` implements the n:m relation between `Student` and `Course`.